Open Razor View as popup from jquery datatable
I am working with an ASP.NET Core MVC app in C#, where I have a window with jQuery datatable (I am using C# and Visual Studio 2022). In this datatable, I have 4 columns. One of the column is link button as shown below:
$("#DATATABLE").DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        filter: true,
        searchDelay: 1000,
        scrollY: StaticData.TABLE_HEIGHT + 'px',
        lengthMenu: StaticData.TABLE_PAGE_SIZE,
        language: { searchPlaceholder: "Stud Code, Stud Group" },
        scrollCollapse: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/STUD_MANAGEMENT/LoadStudents',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
            data: (d) => {                    
                return { draw: d.draw, start: d.start, length: d.length, search: d.search.value, FilterByColumn: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data, ASC_DSEC: d.order[0].dir }
            },
            beforeSend: () => { ShowLoader(); },
            complete: () => { HideLoader(); },
            dataSrc: (json) => {
                json = json.data;
                //console.log(json);                    
                return json;
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [0,2], width: '2%', }],
        columns: [                
            { data: 'STUD_ID', title: 'Stud Id', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
            { data: 'STUD_GROUP', title: 'Student Group', autoWidth: true },
            { data: 'STUD_NAME', title: 'Student Name', autoWidth: true },                              
            { data: null, title: 'Class Model', autoWidth: true,
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                    if(type === 'display')
                    {
                        data = '<a href="' + data.CLASSMODEL + '" onclick = "return onClassModelClick(' + data.STUD_ID+ ')">' + data.CLASSMODEL + '</a>';
                    }
                     return data;
                }
            }
        ]            
        }
});// datatable

The CLASSMODEL is a link button. And the handler code for onClassModelClick() is shown here:
function onDataModelClick(id) {
    // alert(id);           
}

I created a new Razor view (StudNew.cshtml) and I want to popup that Razor view when class model link button is clicked. And the STUD_ID must be passed to the popup window.

Hi @KitKat, so what is your current issue? Could you pls add console.log(data) in the render function? The naming convention for response json in asp.net core is camel case by default. Pls add the log and check it by pressing F12 in browser Console panel.

Also, what is your data.CLASSMODEL and how is the razor view(StudNew.cshtml) like? Do you need pass any model to this view?
